# Error: app.database is not a function using Firebase

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use the Firebase realtime database with Vue. I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: app.database is not a function

My code:

Firebase.js:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
export default firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "HIDDEN",
    authDomain: "HIDDEN",
    databaseURL: "HIDDEN",
    projectId: "HIDDEN",
    storageBucket: "HIDDEN",
    messagingSenderId: "HIDDEN",
    appId: "HIDDEN"
});

export const db = app.database();
export const wordRef = db.ref('Word');
```

I'm trying to use it on a  button.

```
<b-field label="Word">
  <b-input 
            v-model="Word"
            :value="Word"
            @input="Word = $event.target.value"
            ></b-input>
        </b-field>
       <b-button @click="submitData">Submit Me</b-button>
```

```
<script>
import { wordRef } from '../firebase';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Word: ""
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submitData() {
      wordRef.push({Word: this.Word})
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Since the error says *"app.database is not a function"* and not *"app is not defined"*. I'm guessing you have previously defined `app`. Could you add that line to your question? It's rather important. Without it, chances you'll get a useful answer, based on what's actually happening in your code are rather slim.

Comment: As it stands, the question is strictly related to javascript syntax and nothing else. It could be a `react`, `angular` or vanilla application as well as `aws` or `mongodb`, the error would have been the same if you tried to run a non-existent method as a function in a javascript expression.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what `app` is - it's never defined.  However, I think you meant to say `firebase.database()` instead of `app.database()`.

Comment: If `app` was not defined the error would have been *"app is not defined"*.

Comment: @tao I'm not saying it wasn't defined at all.  I'm just saying that the code never showed the definition, so it's not clear what the expectation is for that line of code.

Comment: I only pointed out your assumption was wrong and could have easily been verified. I probably should have said you shouldn't have answered if the answer required making assumptions, which is what [answer] suggests but, considering your rep I realized you already know it, but just don't care about the rules.

Comment: @tao I'm sorry, I don't understand.  I didn't make any assumptions other than what I thought the OP meant to do.  `firebase` in this case does have a `database()` method and it's customary to call it right after init. Do you have an alternative idea?

Comment: Well, that's how I interpreted *"It's not clear from your question what `app` is - it's never defined"*. That, to me, is an assumption. Because a) you can't know that and b) if that assumption was true the body of the error would have been different. That's exactly what I meant when I said *"making assumptions"*. Absolutely nothing else. IMHO, the correct action would have been asking for more details using a comment, not venturing an answer.

Comment: @tao Thanks for your feedback.